# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

**Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport**

those are my dependencies

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>healthcare</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>healthcare</name>
    <description>healthcare</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
            <artifactId>hessian</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.106</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v3-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-spring-v5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.33.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.8</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is desc

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java:76)

The following method did not exist:

org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.messageBrokerTaskScheduler()Lorg/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler;

The calling method's class, org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport, was loaded from the following location:

jar:file:/Users/grigormartirosyan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-websocket/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-websocket-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/Users/grigormartirosyan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-websocket/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-websocket-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport: file:/Users/grigormartirosyan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-websocket/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-websocket-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration: file:/Users/grigormartirosyan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Your dependencies are a incompatible and dangerous mess. 1 remove jackson dependencies, 2 remove the `org.springframework` dependencies, 3. remove the `org.springframework.security` dependency, 4. replace elasticsearch with `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`

Comment: and forgot, add `spring-boot-starter-websocket` as a dependency to use websockets.